# django form field as a list, using post

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Using Django, I need to show a list of all model objects and choose 1 by clicking on it.
example:

forms.py:

```
class new_form(forms.Form):
    x = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

in the view i am checking is request has POST, if not, I am creating new form instance and returning it rendered to the template:

```
if request.POST:
 ...
form = new_form()
form.fields['x'].choices = model_x.objects.filter(FILTER CONDITION).values_list('id','name')
c['form']=form
return render(request, 'orders/tmplt.html',c)
```

in the template i am converting the form field (x) to a list, and adding jquery click listener to it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#x_select li").click(function(){
            MY MISSING CODE
        });
    });
</script>

Please select:
<form id="form" action='#' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.x.errors %}
        {{ form.x.errors }}
        <br>
    {% endif %}
    <ul id="x_select">
    {% for choice in form.x %}
        <li id="{{ choice.choice_value }}"> {{ choice.choice_label }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
    <ul>
    <br>
</form>
```

I want to post back to the view the id value which the client choose by clicking on the list item.

how can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers..
finally i did it like this:
1) created radio buttons list, with django widget (RadioSelect)
2) designed the radios to be hidden with CSS

```
ul li input{ display: none; }
```

3) jquery on click (to the radio and to the list item):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#x_select li ").click(function(){
            $('#x_form').submit();
        });
        $("#x_select li ").click(function(){
            $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);
            $(this).find('input').click();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    location = '/new/path/' + $(this).prop('id');
});
```

your quesiton should have been "how can I redirect to another page on click". This is not a django or python question.

Comment: Hi, few questions: 1) i want to be able to add more fields later, so i will need to hardcode all the fields in the data object. 2) i need the csrf_token as well. is there any smoother way to do it?

Comment: and i do not need Ajax, i need it to redirect my window to the new page.